# How to iterate over nested map or list in Groovy script for Jenkins activeChoices plugin?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

My first job using activeChoicesParameter plugin, and quite a challenge. What I want to achieve is a list of checkboxes, grouped as "main" and "specific" with properly formatted HTML code. The list of possible choices (represented by checkboxes) should be derived from mapping for a specific identifier, represented by 'single select' drop-down list.

So the checkbox list I want to obtain in my build page should look like the following:

[Expected list of choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQC1J.png)

What I tried so far were:

```
test_group_map = [
  "id_1": [
    [test_group : "group_1", test_subgroup : ["subgroup_1", "subgroup_2", "subgroup_3"] ],
    [test_group : "group_2", test_subgroup : ["subgroup_4", "subgroup_5"] ],
  ],
]

html_to_be_rendered = ""

test_groups = test_group_map[ID]
test_groups.each { groups ->
  html_to_be_rendered = """
    ${html_to_be_rendered}
    <li style=\"list-style: none\">
      <input name=\"value\" alt=\"${groups.test_group}\" json=\"${groups.test_group}\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\" \" id=\"option\">
      <label title=\"${groups.test_group}\" class=\" \" for=\"option\">${groups.test_group}</label>
      <ul style=\"list-style: none\">
        <li>
          <input name=\"value\" alt=\"${groups.test_subgroup}\" json=\"${groups.test_subgroup}\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\"subOption\">
          <label title=\"${groups.test_subgroup}\" class=\" \">${groups.test_subgroup}</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
"""
}

html_to_be_rendered = "${html_to_be_rendered}"

return html_to_be_rendered
```

which resulted in:

[Approach with list of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUkTt.png)

My second approach was the following:

```
test_group_map = [
  "id_1": [
    [test_group : "group_1", test_subgroup : "subgroup_1", test_subgroup : "subgroup_2", test_subgroup : "subgroup_3" ],
    [test_group : "group_2", test_subgroup : "subgroup_4", test_subgroup :  "subgroup_5" ],
  ],
]

html_to_be_rendered = ""

test_groups = test_group_map[ID]
test_groups.each { groups ->
  html_to_be_rendered = """
    ${html_to_be_rendered}
    <li style=\"list-style: none\">
      <input name=\"value\" alt=\"${groups.test_group}\" json=\"${groups.test_group}\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\" \" id=\"option\">
      <label title=\"${groups.test_group}\" class=\" \" for=\"option\">${groups.test_group}</label>
      <ul style=\"list-style: none\">
        <li>
          <input name=\"value\" alt=\"${groups.test_subgroup}\" json=\"${groups.test_subgroup}\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\"subOption\">
          <label title=\"${groups.test_subgroup}\" class=\" \">${groups.test_subgroup}</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
"""
}

html_to_be_rendered = "${html_to_be_rendered}"

return html_to_be_rendered
```

which gave me the following result:

[Approach with many values for one key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkLSD.png)

(Note, that enclosing the main part `html_to_be_rendered` variables actually contain some formatting HTML markups, so they are used; I just cut the values for readability)

I tried also iterating over values for 'subgroup' key, but Jenkins gave me nothing (which means HTML code produced from script is not proper, or as far as I understand Groovy script fails at runtime, and doesn't return any HTML).

So finally I believe there is a problem with either iterating over presented mapping, or mapping itself is a cause. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in your first version you want to iterate through `groups.test_subgroup`. I added that iteration to your first version:

```
test_group_map = [
        "id_1": [
                [test_group : "group_1", test_subgroup : ["subgroup_1", "subgroup_2", "subgroup_3"] ],
                [test_group : "group_2", test_subgroup : ["subgroup_4", "subgroup_5"] ],
        ],
]

html_to_be_rendered = ""

String ID = "id_1"
test_groups = test_group_map[ID]

test_groups.each { groups ->
    html_to_be_rendered = """
    ${html_to_be_rendered}
    <li style=\"list-style: none\">
      <input name=\"value\" alt=\"${groups.test_group}\" json=\"${groups.test_group}\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\" \" id=\"option\">
      <label title=\"${groups.test_group}\" class=\" \" for=\"option\">${groups.test_group}</label>
      <ul style=\"list-style: none\">
        <li>""" +
            groups.test_subgroup.collect { name -> """
          <input name=\"value\" alt=\"${name}\" json=\"${name}\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\"subOption\">
          <label title=\"${name}\" class=\" \">${name}</label>"""}.join('<br>') + """
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
"""
}

html_to_be_rendered = "${html_to_be_rendered}"

println html_to_be_rendered
```

If that is getting too ugly think about using [HTML MarkupBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html)

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)

builder.html {
    head {}
    body {
        mkp.yieldUnescaped html_to_be_rendered

        test_groups.each { groups ->
            li(style: "list-style: none") {
                input(name: "value", alt: groups.test_group, json: groups.test_group, type: "checkbox", class: " ", id: "option")
                label(title: groups.test_group, class: " ", for: "option", groups.test_group)
                ul(style: "list-style: none"){
                    li {
                        groups.test_subgroup.each { name ->
                            input(name: "value", alt: name, json: name, type: "checkbox", class: "subOption")
                            label(title: name, class: " ", name)
                            br()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

println(writer.toString())
```

I have not tested any of this in Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly! I am still not very fluent in Groovy (apparently...), but will try MarkupBuilder as well, I agree that it looks very elegant.